# Google Chrome display weird drop down banner of width 1920?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

i'm not sure what's going on, but this banner get displayed initially to every page and pull up on its own...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the WIDTHIE extension got installed and enabled. Odd!

Comment: Bizarre I had this same thing happen. I've never even heard of this extension. Thanks for the fix/post.